# Does ghee make a good substitution for lard?

Tags: substitutions, fat, ghee

I'm trying out a recipe which requires sauteeing something in lard. A lot of people seem to recommend butter as a substitute for lard, but I'm not fond of sauteeing in butter, because of the low smoking point and difficulty in getting it the right heat.

So does ghee work as a substitution for lard (specifically pig lard)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use ghee or oil for sauteing instead of lard.

**NOTE:** You will not get the same "lardy" aroma from butter, ghee or oil, but if you use other stronger aromas / spices in your recipe it might not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Clarified butter (ghee) has one of the highest [smoke points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_point) of any fat. It even has a higher smoke point than lard. In general any fat can be substituted for another fat, it just depends on the taste you are looking for.